# Fineuploader: change the UI filename based on server response

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I have this Fineuploader auto upload widget that send the file to the server, we really don't care about the name of the file the user sends, what we care is what the servers name the file after saving it.

What I want to do is be able to change the name of the file that Fineuploader shows in the Input, is there any desirable way to do it?

Currently I'm sending the new file name in the JSON response an name, and I know that in the onComplete callback I can read that, but I was wondering what's the best way to set the new name after upload.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`setName` method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setName):

```
callbacks: {
    onComplete: function(id, name, response) {
        this.setName(id, response.newName);
    }
}
```

The above code assumes your server is returning a `newName` property in its response to the upload request.  Adjust to suit your situation.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... I'm debugging to see why:
http://puu.sh/8ANU0.png
Fineuploader version: 3.9.0-3

Comment: Sorry, forgot to pass the id, but still it wont change the name.

Comment: There's something else wrong with your code then. The fragment I posted should work just fine.

Comment: Ray: I tried on the console... made sure that 'this' was a fineuploader object and still it wont set the name... see that screenshot, but now I'm passing the id to the function.

Comment: Please show all of your fine-uploader-related code.  The code I posted will work, provided it is used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the FineUploader plugin does not provide a way to rename the file on the server, just a way to rename the filename of what the user sees (by using the method **this.setName(id, response.newName);** ). This might be useful if the user's file is fubar.jpg and it gets renamed to fubar2.jpg because there already is a file named fubar.jpg on the server - in which case you might want the user to see the actual filename of their file and not that on your server.

To solve your issue for a single file upload, you will need to tweak the function "**uploadSingleFile**" in file "**image-uploader.cfc**" by adding the following immediately after the line **`<cffile action="upload" ...`**

```
<!--- We now want to rename the file on our server to prevent any issues with name strings --->
<cfset newFullFileName = "newfile_#randRange(1, 100000000)#.#FILE.serverFileExt#">
<cffile action="rename" source="#fileUploadDirectory#\#FILE.serverFile#" destination="#fileUploadDirectory#\#newFullFileName#">
```

The above renames the uploaded file to "newfile_####" with #### being a random 8-digit number.

You will also need to update the **server_filename** element in the return response like this:

```
<cfset local.response['server_filename'] = newFullFileName>
```

Below is an explanation of a few important return structure elements:

```
<!--- The original file's FULL filename that the user sees (eg. 'contract 123.jpg') --->
<cfset local.response['client_filename'] = FILE.clientFile>

<!--- The file extension of the user's file (eg. jpg, gif, doc, pdf, etc.) --->
<cfset local.response['client_fileextension'] = FILE.clientFileExt> 

<!--- The renamed FULL filename of the uploaded file on our server (eg. cs_83237453.jpg) (OLD WAY: FILE.serverFile) ---> 
<cfset local.response['server_filename'] = newFullFileName>

<!--- The file extension of the uploaded file (eg. jpg, gif, doc, pdf, etc.) --->
<cfset local.response['server_fileextension'] = FILE.serverFileExt>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way don't show the Input==> 
Remark or remove this 2 line on UI , don't let user going to edit the filenames.

```
     <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
<input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
```